# Ajustar o Fullcalendar para exibir inicialmente a aba de semana e não por mês

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Pessoal tenho muito pouco conhecimento em js, porém estou tentando meio que na raça ajustar o fullcalendar para um sisteminha que estou criando. Preciso que ao invés dele inicializar diretamente por "mês", gostaria que a primeira tela fosse a de "semana".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao chamar a função fullcalendar, adicione `defaultView: 'agendaWeek'`.

**Exemplo:**

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({defaultView: 'agendaWeek'});
```

Para alterar a visualização de forma dinâmica utilize `changeView`.

**Exemplo:**

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'changeView', 'agendaWeek' );
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente... Obrigado!